# Cakephp upgrade from 1.3 to 2.06 theme not working

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've battled though a lot of the strict standard errors, but I am stuck with the app not using the correct theme, it keeps loading a page for the default under /View.

I have checked that AppController.php sets

```
$this->viewClass = 'Theme'
$this->theme = 'academy'
```

also the path is correct:

```
app/View/Themed/Academy/
```

But I can't figure out why it keeps using the default. This upgrading business is a nightmare.

Also looking at var_dump($this) in default view shows the theme is set to 'academy.'

Comment: check for individual controller and actions if the theme is described there

Comment: @AshishChoudhary It is only described in the AppController and nowhere else.

Comment: Is there a way for me to debug what is happening with the theme settings?

Comment: You can debug by over writing the theme setting in the action you are using.If its successful, then remove it set it in the before filter in the controller, then the property. Means you have to go backwards if you are not able to find the issue. The place where it will stop taking the theme setting will have the issue.

Comment: I have already done that in the action, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide your directory structure for theme "academy"

Comment: The AppController was pulling the theme name from the database, for some reason ThemeView does not CamelCase this, so I had to manually update the database entry.